# SQL Server 2008: How to measure how long it takes to create/rebuild an index?

Tags: sql-server

I'm rebuilding a nonclustered index on SQL Server 2008 on a fairly large table

Here's the code

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Documents_Title] ON [dbo].[Documents]
(
    -- 3 columns
)
WHERE [deleted]=(0) AND [processing]=(0)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = ON, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Question.. how do I measure the time it takes to rebuild the index?** I'm a .NET developer and I usually use the StopWatch class to measure time/performance. Can I apply a similar technique to measure the time it takes to rebuild? Probably not because it looks the rebuild/creation of an index is asynchronous.

Comment: What makes you think this command is asynchronous?

Comment: so if you put it in a script the script ends, but the process goes on?  I suppose that's possible, SQL server may be busy still doing something - other than that, can you put it in a stored procedure and use a variable to calculate time difference in milliseconds with datediff

Comment: @DavidG I'm assuming it's async because it runs quickly in a blink of an eye like an async call :). Am I wrong to assume it's async?

Comment: The rebuild is definitely not asynchronous. T-SQL is a fully synchronous and sequential language. A batch will not finish until all statements in it are actually done, one by one. If you specify `ONLINE = ON`, the index creation will not block other statements on the same server (which is a kind of asynchrony) but within one session, it's always one darn thing after another.

Comment: If you just need measurements to eyeball things (that is, you don't need to select them and store them somewhere else), `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` should be sufficient. `SET STATISTICS IO ON` will give you more insight in how much SQL Server had to do with the disk while it built the index (probably less than you think).

Comment: What do you class as a "fairly large table"? Reindexing can be super quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jeroen Mostert's did the trick for me. Executing `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` and `SET STATISTICS TIME ON` gave me the stats that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

The `ALTER INDEX ... REBUILD` will do it synchronously.

```
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()

ALTER INDEX [idx_Documents_Title] ON [dbo].[Documents] REBUILD

DECLARE @EndTime DATETIME = SYSDATETIME()

SELECT 
    StartTime = @StartTime, 
    EndTime = @EndTime,
    DifferenceInMinutes = DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @StartTime, @EndTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @START_TIME DATETIME
SET @START_TIME = GETDATE()

--your index creation code or whatever you'd like to measure

SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND, @START_TIME, GETDATE()) AS TOTAL_SECONDS
```

You can wrap your code with a `@START_TIME` and find the `DATEDIFF` you may find that it's running so fast that it's `0` seconds.

I'm sure there a few clever ways to do this, but this is the general idea.